# Create Multiple Subplots of sns.factorplot based on Dataframe Integer Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, subplot

I have a dataframe like on below,
df_sales:

```
               ProductCode  Weekly_Units_Sold Is_Promo
  Date

  2015-01-11      1               49.0       No
  2015-01-11      2               35.0       No
  2015-01-11      3               33.0       No
  2015-01-11      4               40.0       No
  2015-01-11      5               53.0       No
    ...          ...                ...      ...
  2015-07-26     313               93.0      No
  2015-07-26     314                4.0      No
  2015-07-26     315                1.0      No
  2015-07-26     316                5.0      No
  2015-07-26     317                2.0      No
```

Want to observe Promotime effect on Each ProductCode with Sns.factorplot like code on below:

```
sns.factorplot(data= df_sales,
                x= 'Is_Promo',
                y= 'Weekly_Units_Sold',
                hue= 'ProductCode');
```

It is working good but it seems very confusing and overlapped due to 317 product plotted in one table.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgrjV.png)

When i split the dataframe with this code:

```
df_sales=df_sales.query('1<=ProductCode<=10')
```

It looks great readbility. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQev.png

So, ı wanted to draw as subplots with help of splitting data respect of 10 productcode range(like first subplot ProductCOde is [1-10], second[11-20]..[291-300],[301-310],[311-317] in each subplot.

My Failed Tries :`

```
g=sns.FacetGrid(df_sales,col='ProductCode')
   g.map(sns.factorplot,'Is_Promo','Weekly_Units_Sold')
   sns.factorplot(data= df_sales,
               x= 'Is_Promo',
               y= 'Weekly_Units_Sold',
               hue= 'ProductCode');
```

I tried not splitting with 10 ProductCode ranges. 
I have just tried to create subplot for each ProductCode but 
gave me image size error.

So how can I create subplots of sns.factorplot splitted respect to ProductCode range to get more readible results?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new column with a unique value for each group of products. A simple way of doing that is using [`pd.cut()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
Nproducts = 100
Ngroups = 10
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'ProductCode':np.arange(Nproducts),
                    'Weekly_Units_Sold': np.random.random(size=Nproducts),
                    'Is_Promo':'No'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ProductCode':np.arange(Nproducts),
                    'Weekly_Units_Sold': np.random.random(size=Nproducts),
                    'Is_Promo':'Yes'})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
df['ProductGroup'] = pd.cut(df['ProductCode'], Ngroups, labels=False)
```

After that, you can facet based on `ProductGroup`, and plot whatever relationship you want for each group.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='ProductGroup', col_wrap=3, hue='ProductCode')
g.map(sns.pointplot, 'Is_Promo', 'Weekly_Units_Sold', order=['No','Yes'])
```

[image]

Note that this using seaborn v.0.10.0. `factorplot()` was renamed `catplot` in v.0.9 so you may have to adjust for version difference.

**EDIT:** to create a legend, I had to modify a bit the code to move the `hue` parameter out of the FacetGrid:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='ProductGroup', col_wrap=3)
g.map_dataframe(sns.pointplot, 'Is_Promo', 'Weekly_Units_Sold', order=['Yes','No'], hue='ProductCode')
for ax in g.axes.ravel():
    ax.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(1.1,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much it looks perfect. But i am quiet new in python so i need to ask two silly question. First how i can put my actual data rather than this np.random part in dict 'Weekly_Units_Sold': np.random.random(size=Nproducts).I should convert my df_sales to dictionary format?. And  you took it 100 as a size of groups.But what if let say it is 107, Would it be still work like 10 groups wit h10 uniform batch size +1 group with 7 batch?

Comment: just replace your own dataframe in the call:  `g=sns.FacetGrid(data=df_sales,...)`

Comment: look at the documentation of `pd.cut()` and play around. If you want 10 groups with 10, and the last group with 7, you may have to provide a sequence of bin edges to `bins=`

Comment: Thanks again, everything worked great. I have just one extra question if you answer i would be glad. As also in your example, can we add smth like plt.legend logic to each ProdutGroup to define which color is belong to which ProductCode?

Comment: You are legend, total respect. But why the package is choosing so close color tone each other rather than more distinguisahble color tones, dont you think a little annoying?:)

Comment: You Can pass colors or cmaps to pointplot using the palette= argument. See documentation https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html